# Set scrollHeight on HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lot of empty space at the bottom of my HTML page, most likely because there is a transparent flash move loaded as a fallback. Is it possible to set the `scrollHeight` so there is no useless empty space at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `display:none` on the HTML element that serves as the container for the flash fallback content.